# If matrix $A$ is similar to matrix $B$, then matrix $A^2 + A + I$ is similar to $B^2+B+I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Prove that if matrix $A$ is similar to matrix $B$, then matrix $A^2 + A + I$ is similar to $B^2+B+I$

Comment: what is matrix $E$?

Comment: Identity matrix

Comment: I downvoted this question because it shows no effort and the solution is very basic

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are similar, then $p(A)$ and $p(B)$ are similar for any polynomial $p$. In fact, it is true in more generality, for example, take $f$ to be entire, then $f(A)$ is similar to $f(B)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$A$ is similar to matrix $B$ implies there exists a matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1}BP$

Now $A^2 + A + E = P^{-1}[B^2 +B+E]P$.

Hence matrix $A^2 + A + E$ is similar to $B^2+B+E$.

---

Used Facts: $A^2 = P^{-1}BPP^{-1}BP = P^{-1}B^2P$ and $E = P^{-1}P$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: By assumption we have $B=SAS^{-1}$ with invertible $S$. Now compute $B^2+B^1+B^0$. Note that $B^k=SA^kS^{-1}$ for all $k\ge 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is similar to $B$, then there is an invertible matrix $P$, such that

$P^{-1}AP=B$

By computing $B^2=P^{-1}APP^{-1}AP=P^{-1}A^2P$

Which means $A^2$ and $B^2$ are similar.

Now apply $P$ and $P^{-1}$ to $A^2+A+E$ to get

$P^{-1}(A^2+A+E)P=P^{-1}A^2P+P^{-1}AP+E=B^2+B+E$